# Unable to receive In-App purchase refund server-to-server notification

Tags: ios, server, notifications, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement handling of In-App purchase refund notification (App Store sends responseBody JSON data to server notification url typed by the app developer) in our server backend. But after getting successful refund of In-App purchase, I'm unable to get any notification from the App Store.

Here's the list of things that I did to handle refund notification in our server.

1. Goto **App Store Connect** > Type "App Store Notification Url" : "https://ourServerUrl/notifyRefund" (supports TLS 1.2)
2. Our server accepts 'POST' request and defines @RequestBody parameter as documented in [responseBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody)
3. Purchase product ('Consumable') from our iOS App (about $0.99) - **purchase_date = 2021-03-03**
4. Goto **reportaproblem.apple.com** and request a refund. -> Next day the refund was processed by App Store and I got $0.99 refunded successfully to my bank account. **refund_date = 2021-03-04**

After doing above steps I'm still unable to get a notification from App Store.
I read a post about [notification delay](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659741) but I'm not sure if this is because of the delay or my server configuration has a problem.

[Apple doc.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications)

Answer (score 0):

Update as of 2021-03-24
In Server <--> App (iOS/Android) communication,
our server's view resolver (ContentNegotiatingViewResolver) determines the default view (TextPlainView, JsonView)
based on the request header (Content-Type, Accept)

Since the apple notification callback response (request to our server)
does not have 'Accept' header, our server sets default view resolver as TextPlainView
following our server configuration in 'servlet-context.xml'
It has caused errors since Apple notification response is in Json format.

After changing our server default view setting as json view
we were able to parse apple notification responseBody.
I hope it helps developers dealing with similar problems.